# reported to have been... yesterday

Tags: passive-voice

> Twenty tourists are reported to have been injured in the crash yesterday.

"Have been" and "yesterday" in one sentence confuse me. My version would be so:

> Twenty tourists are reported to be injured in the crash yesterday.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 2 sounds somehow unusual to me, the way you built it. This would be better:

> Twenty tourists are reported as injured after the crash yesterday.

I would prefer sentence 1 at any time.

Short explanation: In sentence 1, crash is related to injured. In sentence 2, crash is more related to reported.

Comment: "sounds off"? What do you mean? "reported to be injured" seems to be a perfectly fine construction, you can find it in a lot of articles if you google it.

Comment: @RubioRic: Tnx for the comment. I edited to express better what I intended to say. Even though I have a very good level of English, I am not a native English speaker - therefore I am not adapted to some "ways of saying things".

Answer (score 0):

**Reported to have been** sounds completely normal to me.

Twenty tourists are reported to have been injured in the crash yesterday.

If we change the voice of your example
It goes on like this;

It is reported that twenty tourists were injured in the crash yesterday.

To have been works like was/were in infinitive form

Whereas to be is more like is/are